# Handling fetch errors when response returns appropriate error message React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling, fetch

I have the following fetch function

```
request(url, options) {
  return fetch(url, _.defaultsDeep(options || {}, defaultOptions))
     .then(handleErrors)
     .then(response => response.json())
     .catch(error => handleFetchError(error));
}
```

The `handleErrors` function does the following to check if the response failed...

```
function handleErrors(response) {
   if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(response.statusText);
   }
   return response;
}
```

The issue I am having is that the API returns a `400` status, but also an array with a relevant error message(s) but using `throw new Error(response.statusText);` just returns some generic error message `Error: [object Object]`with no was to access the errors array.

This is what I expected to be returned in the response

```
{
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "errors": [
                   { "defaultMessage": "Please check that your name contains only letters and is longer than two characters" }
              ]
}
```

I do not have access to the API server side, so I cannot change anything there.

But is there a method that I can throw an error to catch but also get access to the `errors` array within the response?

### EDIT:

In `handleErrors` this is the response object I recieve

```
{
  "type": "default",
  "status": 401,
  "ok": false,
  "statusText": "",
  "headers": {
    "map": {
      "pragma": "no-cache",
      "date": "Wed, 01 May 2019 07:44:40 GMT",
      "x-content-type-options": "nosniff",
      "x-frame-options": "DENY",
      "content-type": "application/json;charset=ISO-8859-1",
      "cache-control": "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate",
      "content-length": "53",
      "x-xss-protection": "1; mode=block",
      "expires": "0"
    }
  },
  "url": "http://localhost:8080/login",
  "_bodyInit": {},
  "_bodyBlob": {}
}
```

When I throw the error and try to access it in `handleFetchError` the `error` argument is just an empty object `{}`

Comment: 'Error: [object object]' is just the console output hiding the actual underlying object when it uses `toString()`. Could you please do a `console.log(JSON.stringify(Error)` to see what the object looks like? And update your question with that info?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to throw `response.statusText` but your response doesn't have that property. It has `status`.

Comment: I'm not at my machine at the moment but I do recall that the response in `handleError` is not the same as the response I get from the API. The response in `handleErrors` does include the property `statusText` and headers etc.

Comment: If you could please update your question with the correct code, I can try to figure it out.

Comment: Well, the code is correct but I can update the response argument I receive in `handleErrors`, but that won't be until tomorrow. I know for certain it does not include the response from the API with the errors array, just seems to be a response from `fetch` to aid in handle errors?

Comment: Yes, please update the response output, along with adding the other info I asked for in another comment.

Comment: I have updated my question with the response and console log

Comment: Where exactly are you seeing `Error: [object Object]`? This seems to indicate the error was correctly created and thrown and it's just a matter of the way that error is getting logged or displayed.